# Как организовать работу PHPStorm, SASS и Webpack, чтобы переменные импортированные в головном файле распознавались в остальных файлах?

Tags: webpack, phpstorm, sass, scss

В головном .scss-файле я последовательно подключаю файл с переменными, и файлы конкретных секций. Это выглядит так:

```
@import 'variables'
@import 'header'
@import 'footer'
```

Если не написать в начале каждой секции `@import 'variables'`, то PHPStorm подчеркнёт использование переменных и расширяемых модулей, как вызванные без должного объявления.

Импортирование в начале файла каждой секции не просто использует переменные — происходит импорт всего файла. Поэтому такой вариант не подойдёт. Вдобавок это нарушает работу стилей. На официальном сайте SASS предлагают использовать `@use`, однако там же указывают, что его поддержки ещё нигде нет.

Можно ли как-то навести порядок в этом вопросе, пока разработчики не ввели поддержку `@use`?

Comment: Что значит _"не просто использует переменные — происходит импорт всего файла"_ ? В `variables` не должно быть никаких стилей, только переменные! Ну и опять же, а чем вам мешает "подчеркивание"?

Comment: @DmitryKozlov в переменных я указал и расширяемые шаблоны, которые использую через `@extend %template`. Они также подчёркиваются. И тогда при импорте файлы некорректно конкатенируются, добавляется дублирование и перезаписывание кода.

А подчёркивание мне мешает тем, что я могу действительно ошибочно использовать переменную/шаблон, или столкнуться с такой проблемой, открыв чужой код. И не узнать об этом. Раз IDE даёт возможность — надо пользоваться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй использовать инъекцию файла с константами и миксинами в функции **prependData**

```
use: [
                        {
                            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader
                        },
                        {
                            loader: 'css-loader'
                        },
                        {
                            loader: 'postcss-loader',
                            options: {
                                plugins: () => [autoprefixer]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            loader: 'resolve-url-loader'
                        },
                        {
                            loader: 'sass-loader',
                            options: {
                                prependData: (loaderContext) => {
                                    const constants = fs.readFileSync('./frontend/common/constants.scss', "utf8");
                                    return constants;
                                },
                                sourceMap: true
                            }
                        }
                    ]
```